# How to loop through a list of string values in SAS

Tags: sas, do-loops

I am working on a project where I have a list of 45 codes. My goal is to find all codes that start with the first 3 characters of the code.

For example, I need to find all codes that start with N31, N32,N33....N34. I have figured out how to do this manually in SAS (use a where code like N31_ or code like N32_)

```
data slice;
set dat.all_hcpcs_nitos;

where nitos like "N30_"
or nitos like "N31_";
run;
```

I am not looking forward to hard coding this 45 times and am hoping to find something...more elegant. If I were in python, I would make a list of the 45 codes then iterate through each one in the list. I am unsure how to do this type of process in SAS.

From my searching it looks like I may need to do a %let codes = "list of codes". I have also tried doing something like i = 1 to 8 and try to do a search like:

```
data slice;
set dat.all_hcpcs_nitos;

%do i = 1 to 8;
where nitos like "N3&i._";
%end;
run;
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestions. I have been challenging myself on making my code more compact, and the SAS macros always look confusing to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `IN` operator with the `:` modifier to have it do a trimmed comparison.
Example:

```
proc print data=sashelp.class;
  where name in: ('Ali','Bar');
run;
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I tried it but I got 0 observations. I am thinking it is because I still need the "like" operator. So I need all observations that start with N31...N32...

Comment: Do you just want the values that start with those strings then use `where nitos in: ('N31' 'N32' ....)` If you want to limit it to just 4 character strings then add `and length(nitos)=4`.

Comment: Check what values you actually have.  `proc freq; tables nitos; format nitos $3.;run;`

Comment: No so I need all of the codes that start with N31X, where X can be any number/letter and I still need the last character.

Thinking aloud, I can cut the code to the first 3, use your code, and then map it back to the original data to get the full code again. A little convoluted but it would work and be better than doing a 100 line SQL code.

If you have a suggestion to make it even better, I'm all ears! But I think this will definitely be better than what I had come up with

Comment: No need to change the code as it is NOT changing any data. What the `:` modifier does is change the behavior of the comparison operator, it does not change the data.